# Dynamics D365FO X++ subscribe to C#.NET Event

Tags: c#, events, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

I have written a C# Class Library which is referenced by dll in a Dynamics D365FO project.

In the C# library I have implemented a custom eventhandler.

How can I subscribe to this custom event in my D365 project?

Here is the C# code implemented in my class library:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;

namespace Azure.ServiceBus.Application
{
    public delegate void ServiceBusMessageReceivedEventHandler(object sender, ServiceBusMessageReceivedEventArgs e);

    public class ServiceBusMessageReceivedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        private readonly Message ReceivedMessage;

        public ServiceBusMessageReceivedEventArgs(Message receivedMessage)
        {
            ReceivedMessage = receivedMessage;
        }
        public Message GetReceivedMessage()
        {
            return ReceivedMessage;
        }
    }

    public class MessageReceiver
    {
        public event ServiceBusMessageReceivedEventHandler ServiceBusMessageReceived;

        public virtual void OnServiceBusMessageReceived(ServiceBusMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ServiceBusMessageReceived != null)
            {
                ServiceBusMessageReceived(this, e);
            }
        }

        public void ReceiveMessages()
        {
            Message message;

            //... receive message

            OnServiceBusMessageReceived(new ServiceBusMessageReceivedEventArgs(message));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Go through this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-operations/dev-itpro/dev-tools/write-business-logic